# Fixed points and infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the formula $1 + \frac{y}2$. This has a fixed point at $y = 2$. And if we use the equation $y = 1 + \frac{y}2$ to substitute for $y$ in our formula, we get $1 + \frac{1 + \frac{y}2}2$, or $1 + \frac12 + \frac{y}4$. If we keep repeating we get $1+\frac12 + \frac14 + \dots$, which does indeed equal our fixed point $2$.

But now consider the formula $1+2y$. This has a fixed point at $y=-1$. Here if we use the equation $y = 1+2y$ to substitute for $y$ in our formula, we get $1+2(1+2y)$, or $1+2+4y$. If we keep repeating we get $1+2+4+\dots$, which does not equal our fixed point $-1$.

Can someone explain in simple terms why this procedure works in the first case but not the second? Would the procedure work in every case where the generated series converged?

Comment: Some people could argue that $1+2+4+8+\cdots=-1$, no kidding. You just need to know how to assign values to a divergent series ; perhaps this could be done using complex analysis.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Banach fixed-point theorem. It explains, why your first sequence behaves as it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_4_%2B_8_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) that $1+2+4+\cdots$ could equal $-1$, to answer your question, there are two classes of fixed points.

An **attractive fixed point** is a fixed point where within a certain range, a point fed into the formula recursively will eventually converge to the fixed point. Your first example is an attractive fixed point.

A fixed point that is not attractive has no points converging to the fixed point when fed into the formula recursively. Your second example is a non-attractive fixed point.

The property of attractive fixed points is that the derivative (i.e., slope) of the function in the formula has magnitude less than $1$ on the range of points that converges to the fixed point:

$$|f'(x)|<1$$

where $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ is the recursive formula.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29) (fixed point) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) (fixed-point iteration) for more information and a clearer explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I had the concept of an attractive fixed point but didn't know this label for it. The [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29) link gives that condition on the derivative as merely being sufficient for attractiveness, whereas your gloss suggests it's both necessary and sufficient. Did you mean to claim that?

Comment: I realize now that I have claimed a statement with a stronger statement than the Wikipedia page. I said that the __range__ of values that converge to the fixed point need to have derivative less than $1$, while the Wikipedia page merely requires that the fixed point have derivative less than $1$. That makes my condition "more sufficient", but it makes it not necessary! See [this](http://tinyurl.com/chessant27094); it shows that an initial point $x_i=1.95$ can still converge to the fixed point $x_0=0$ even though the derivative of $g(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{2}x$ at $x_i$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: (cont'd) So to answer your question, as written my answer is not a necessary condition. However, I am curious to know whether the Wikipedia page's condition is necessary. I couldn't find anything on that, but I have an intuition that it might be. Sorry for the confusion in my answer.